# Iron-router version 1.0.12 is not supported on Jellybean version of Android

Tags: android, meteor, iron-router, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Iron-router version 1.0.12 is not supported on Jellybean version of Android. The latest version (1.0.12) is working fine in the latest version of Android, but in Jellybean it couldn't find the routes and instead it only shows a white screen.

Comment: So far I have tried to downgrade iron:router version to iron:router@1.0.0-pre4 , iron:router@1.0.0-pre3 and iron:router@1.0.0-pre2 and tried running on jellybean but it always gives white screen only .but all the three versions are working on upper android versions